# How to reassign a list (in typescript) based on a "rank" object property?

Tags: javascript, list, typescript

I am trying to make a function to reassign a list based on their rank property.
For example:(my object has other property)

```
var array=[
{id:1,rank:2},
{id:18,rank:1},
{id:53,rank:3},
{id:3,rank:5},
{id:19,rank:4},//this item
]
```

This item {id:19,rank:4} is now in 2d position. The array becomes

```
 item= { currentRank: 4; newRank: 2} //see below

    array=[
    {id:1,rank:3},
    {id:18,rank:1},
    {id:53,rank:4},
    {id:3,rank:5},
    {id:19,rank:2},
    ]
```

FYI : These items are re-order after a html drag&drop operation.
So I am trying to make a function to re-assign ranks based on the droped item rank.
I know the drop item new rank and its old rank.

So far I have done the following but it is not working for all cases:

```
public reorderArray(item: { currentRank: string; newRank: string }, array: { id: string, rank: string }[]): { id: string, rank: string } [] {


      let arr = array.map(a => Object.assign({}, a)).sort((a, b) => (parseInt(a.rank) - parseInt(b.rank))).slice();
      //To avoid to change the reference??
      let isOrdered = arr.every((element, index, array) => {
        return array[index + 1] ? element.rank + 1 == array[index + 1].rank : true
      });

  if (isOrdered && arr[0].rank == (1).toString()) {


    if (parseInt(item.currentRank) < parseInt(item.newRank)) {
      //on descend un élément dans la liste => +1 entre le currentRank et )le newRank
      for (let i = parseInt(item.currentRank); i < parseInt(item.newRank); i++) {
        arr[i].rank = (parseInt(arr[i].rank) - 1).toString();
      }
      arr[parseInt(item.currentRank)].rank = (parseInt(item.newRank)).toString();
    }
    else if (parseInt(item.currentRank) > parseInt(item.newRank)) {
      for (let i = parseInt(item.newRank); i < parseInt(item.currentRank); i++) {
        arr[i].rank = (parseInt(arr[i].rank) + 1).toString();
      }
      arr[parseInt(item.currentRank)].rank = (parseInt(item.newRank) + 1).toString();
    }
    return arr


  }
  else {
    alert("This list is not ordered");
  }
}
```

nb: if array is not properly oredered (rank is 1,3,4...), function doesn't do anything.

Comment: Can you put an example of what you'd like the output to be?

Comment: I have edited and added an example.

Comment: i dont understand your question. how does `.sort` not handle this natively?

Comment: Because I don't want to sort, I want to reassign rank propery. This is why i "shuffled" on purpose my object. My problem is not to sort, but to reassign the rank.

Comment: do you want to "reassign" or "reorder"? your question is titled "reorder" which makes me think `.sort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array for splicing and iterate then for the correction of the range.

```js
function changeRank(object) {
    ranks.splice(object.newRank - 1, 0, ranks.splice(object.currentRank - 1, 1)[0]);
    ranks.forEach(function (a, i) {
        a.rank = i + 1;
    });
}

var array = [{ id: 1, rank: 2 }, { id: 18, rank: 1 }, { id: 53, rank: 3 }, { id: 3, rank: 5 }, { id: 19, rank: 4 }],
    ranks = [];

array.forEach(a => ranks[a.rank - 1] = a);

console.log(array);
changeRank({ currentRank: 4, newRank: 2 });
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be approaching this incorrectly.

Why not loop through all of the items and then if the rank is equal too or great then the current one increase it's rank? Then once you're done set the rank for the updated item:

Something like this:

```
for(var x = 0; x < items.length; x++){
    if(items[x].rank >= item.newRank && items[x].rank <= item.currentRank){
        items[x].rank++;
    }
}
item.rank = item.newRank;
```

Comment: It depends where I drop the item. It can be increasing ranks or decreasing them.

Comment: And the list can be very large.

Comment: It's faster then the current accepted answer, you can see the test here: https://jsfiddle.net/84eqo2se/

Answer (score 0):

This logic must work. I've done it with the concept of array. Consider array index as rank.

```
if (new_rank < current_rank)
{
    item = arr[current_rank] 
    i = new_rank;  
    temp = arr[i]; 
    i++;

    while(i<current_rank)
    {
        temp1 = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
        temp = temp1;
        i++;
    }

    arr[new_rank] = item;
}

else
{
    item = arr[current_rank] 
    i = new_rank; 
    temp = arr[i]; 
    i--;

    while(i>current_rank)
    {
        temp1 = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
        temp = temp1;
        i--;
    }

    arr[new_rank] = item;
}
```